how to print below given pattern
. 
. + 
. + * 
. + * + 
. + * + * 
. + * + * + 
. + * + * + * 
. + * + * + * + 
. + * + * + * + * 
. + * + * + * + * + 

This is my code, please help me to find the right Answer
num = int(input("Enter a number"))

for i in range (1,num+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        if j ==1:
            dot = "."
            print(dot,end=" ")
        elif j ==2:
            plus = "+"
            print(plus,end=" ")
        elif j==3:
            star = "*"
            print(star,end=" ")    
    print()


num = int(input("Enter a number "))

for i in range(1, num + 1):
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        
        if j == 1:
            dot = "."
            print(dot, end=" ")
        elif j % 2 == 0:
            plus = "+"
            print(plus, end=" ")
        elif j % 2 == 1:
            star = "*"
            print(star, end=" ")    
    print()

you missed a %

it's not the good pattern: you're printing .+*.+*.+*.+* op wants .+*+*+*

Plus, it is over complicated. for i in range(7): print("." + " + *"*(i//2) + " +"*(i%2))

@chrslg I just wanted to keep his structure. He was trying to undestand what is wrong in his code I assume

I get that. I usually do the same. Except that, in this case, they are obviously not really interested by understanding what is wrong (the question is not "what is wrong", nor "how can I repeat the pattern", or, "how to handle case 4,5,6,7,... without enumerating them all"... The question is "please, do it for me" :D. I am pretty sure they are more interested by a working but mysterious method rather than a non-working but understandable one :D).

Currently you're only checking if the value is strictly equal to 1 , 2 , 3 and then printing , whereas what you need to do is use % operator to check whether on dividing by 2 which char is to be printed. Better understood through code :
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        if j == 0:
            print(". ", end="")
        elif j % 2 == 0:
            print("+ ", end="")
        else:
            print("* ", end="")
    print()  

